# inserting an image and thenfilepath to the database

Tags: asp.net

I'm designing in my web page:

```
namespace photoshops
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             onflbload(sender, e);
        }
        public void onflbload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a byte[] from the input file

            int len = flbload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            byte[] pic = new byte[len];
            flbload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(pic, 0, len);
            // Insert the image and comment into the database

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DEVI\SQLEXPRESS; 
                          Initial Catalog =cat; Integrated Security=SSPI");

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblphotosettings " +
                    "(BillNo,CustomerName,Address,StartDate,EndDate,Systemurl,Numberofcopies,Amount,Total)  
                    values (@BillNo,@CustomerName,@Address,@StartDate,@EndDate,@Systemurl,@Numberofcopies,@Amount,@Total)", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BillNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =TextBox2.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Rdbsdate.SelectedDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Rdbddate.SelectedDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Systemurl", SqlDbType.Image).Value = pic;
                SqlParameter Src = new SqlParameter("@FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar, 450);
                Src.Value = pic.GetName();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(Src);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Numberofcopies", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =TextBox7.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox8.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox9.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

My error

```
Error   1   'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'GetName'   
and no extension method 'GetName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could 
be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 
2008\Projects\photoshops\photoshops\photosetting.aspx.cs    52  29  photoshops
```

Comment: An offtopic comment : System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show - Will not work in ASPX

Comment: @vs dev it is not exacly true, it will work but it will be displayed on server side

Comment: @Paweł Smejda : Did you tried it ever? How it works? MessageBox stop the execution of the code, and wait for user input; and if it shows in the server side, how user will come to know?

Comment: @vs dev yes I tried on VS development server

Comment: @Tom Gullen image location not store in database sqlsever2005

Comment: image location not store in database sqlsever2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the image location in the database.

Your code actually has the `byte[]` being used in the `INSERT` statement:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Systemurl", SqlDbType.Image).Value = pic;
```

Suggest pick one:

- Continue with saving the binary to the database as you have above.
- Save the `byte[]` as a file to a location on disk. Use that filename like so:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImagePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = myImagePathOnDisk;
```

Comment: @p.campbell i use but error is Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a String.

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag error is Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a String.

Comment: @vimal: you need to implement some code to actually save the image to disk, determine the filename on disk, and use that as `myImagePathOnDisk`. My answer is only trying to guide you to an overall solution.

Comment: @curt Error is Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a String.

Comment: @Lertwut W.Error is Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a String

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do code 2 line through that you can be able store image from filepath and can be able to store into database.

```
string flPath = "C:\\1\\noimg.png";
byte[] imageBytes =  File.ReadAllBytes(flPath);
```

`imageBytes` is your part of interest holding whole arrays of bytes of your image, you just need  to insert this to column of table of image datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
string filename = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
         if (filename != "")
            {

                ImageName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();

                ImagePath = Server.MapPath("Images");
                SaveLocation = ImagePath + "\\" + ImageName;
                SaveLocation1 = "~/Image/" + ImageName;
                sl1 = "Images/" + ImageName;
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);

            }...........try it for image
```